# Libman copying folders from subdirectories but not root directory while using filesystem provider

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using libman For managing client side libraries, and using the fileSystem provider.

Facing this issue:

```
    {
      "library": "Content/.",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/animate/",
      "files": [ "animate.css" ]
    },
    {
      "library": "../../fonts/font-awesome/css",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/font-awesome/",
      "files": [ "font-awesome.css" ]
    },
```

The font-awesome library is copied to the destination while the animate is not copied to the destination. The source libs exist.

I also tried Content instead of Content/. but this isn't working too. This issue is causing the build to fail as the BundlerMinifier.BundlerBuildTask is failing.

This is happening with other libs too like:

```
   {
      "library": "../../Scripts/.",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/modernizr/",
      "files": [ "modernizr-2.6.2.js" ]
   }
```

What is the appropriate solution for this?